# Imagemagick - convert psd to jpg - generates blank images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, psd

I used the following code in ruby to generate psds into jpgs -

```
process_file = abc.psd[0]
jpg_file = abc.jpg

system ("convert #{process_file} "\
  "-profile '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/AdobeRGB1998.icc' "\
  "-profile '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc'"\
  "-scale 3072x3072 -quiet #{jpg_file} ")
```

But for few psds, the generated jpgs were blank images in server. After some research, i found a method to `-flatten`, but it didn't always earn the right result. So, is there a one solution that fits all, which works with any layers of psds (and of any size psd). Any tweak to the above code is appreciated.

The code changes when i used flatten:

```
process_file = abc.psd
jpg_file = abc.jpg

system ("convert #{process_file} "\
  "-profile '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/AdobeRGB1998.icc' "\
  "-profile '#{Rails.root}/lib/folder_name/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc' "\
  "-flatten -scale 3072x3072 -quiet #{jpg_file} ")
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain on this, but I suspect it has something to do with previews.

I believe Adobe generally create a preview of the entire document as the first *"layer"* in a `PSD` and your script may be failing when there is no embedded preview and then you need to have **ImageMagick** gather all the layers and flatten them into a single, consistent whole image.

I would suggest you check your options in **Photoshop** as to whether you are embedding previews. Sorry this is not my most specific answer ever but it may help.